# Leaflet Draw "Cannot read property 'enable' of undefined" adding control to geoJSON layer

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.draw

I am trying to use leaflet's edit function on polygons that I loaded from my database. When I click on leaflet's edit button I get the error
`Cannot read property 'enable' of undefined`

[This thread](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw/issues/398) describes a similar problem, and user ddproxy said

> "Since FeatureGroup extends LayerGroup You can walk through the layers
>   presented and add them individually to the FeatureGroup used for
>   Leaflet.draw"

I am confused what he means by "walk through", I thought I was adding a layer group, so i'm not sure what I would be walking through. Does this have to do with the fact that i'm adding the polygons as a geoJSON object? 
 Adding the polygons to the map, binding their popups, and assigning them custom colors works perfectly FYI.

The following is the relevant code:

```
<script>
window.addEventListener("load", function(event){
    //other stuff
    loadHazards(); 

});

//next 6 lines siply add map to page
var osmUrl = 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
var osmAttrib = '&copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
var osm = L.tileLayer(osmUrl, { maxZoom: 18, attribution: osmAttrib})
var map = new L.Map('map', { center: new L.LatLng(39.255467, -76.711964), zoom: 16 })

osm.addTo(map);

var drawnItems = L.featureGroup().addTo(map);
var Hazards = L.featureGroup().addTo(map);

L.control.layers({
        'osm': osm.addTo(map)
        },
        {
           'drawlayer': drawnItems,
           "Hazards" : Hazards,
           "Tickets": Tickets
         },

         {
           position: 'topleft', collapsed: false
         }
         ).addTo(map);

map.addControl(new L.Control.Draw({
    edit: {
        featureGroup: Hazards,
        poly: {
            allowIntersection: false
        }
    },
    draw: {
        polygon: {
            allowIntersection: false,
            showArea: true
        },
        rectangle:false,
        circle:false,
        circlemarker:false
    }
}));

map.on(L.Draw.Event.CREATED, function (event) {
    var layer = event.layer;
    drawnItems.addLayer(layer);
});

</script>
```

And the loadHazards() function:

```
function loadHazards(){
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url:'/loadPolygonFromDatabase',
    success : function(polygons){           
        polygons = JSON.parse(polygons);

        var toAdd = [];
        for (i in polygons){

            var item = {
                    "type" : "Feature",
                    "properties":{
                        "category":"",
                        "description":"",
                        "ID":""
                     },
                     "geometry" : {
                        "type":"Polygon",
                        "coordinates":[],

                    }

            };

            item["geometry"]["coordinates"][0] = polygons[i]["coordinates"];
            item["properties"]["category"]     = polygons[i]["category"];
            item["properties"]["description"]  = polygons[i]["description"];
            item["properties"]["ID"]  = polygons[i]["ID"];
            toAdd.push(item);

        }

        //Add information to popup
        var layerGroup = L.geoJSON(toAdd, {
            onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
                layer.bindPopup(  '<h1>' + feature.properties.category + '</h1>'
                                + '<p>'  + feature.properties.description + '</p>');
                layer.id = feature.properties.ID;

          },
          style: function(feature){
             switch (feature.properties.category) {
                case 'Rabid_Beavers': return {color: "#663326"};
                case 'Fire':   return {color: "#ff0000"};
                case 'Flood':   return {color: "#0000ff"};
            }
          }
        }).addTo(Hazards);

    }
});
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately Leaflet.draw plugin does not handle nested Layer Groups (same for Feature Groups / GeoJSON Layer Groups).

That is the meaning of the [Leaflet.draw #398](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw/issues/398) issue you reference: they advise looping through the *child* layers of your Layer/Feature/GeoJSON Layer Group (e.g. with their [`eachLayer`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#layergroup-eachlayer) method). If the child layer is a non-group layer, then add it to your editable Feature Group. If it is another nested group, then loop through its own child layers again.

See the code proposed in that post:

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/203540/how-to-edit-an-existing-layer-using-leaflet

```js
var geoJsonGroup = L.geoJson(myGeoJSON);
addNonGroupLayers(geoJsonGroup, drawnItems);

// Would benefit from https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/4461
function addNonGroupLayers(sourceLayer, targetGroup) {
  if (sourceLayer instanceof L.LayerGroup) {
    sourceLayer.eachLayer(function(layer) {
      addNonGroupLayers(layer, targetGroup);
    });
  } else {
    targetGroup.addLayer(sourceLayer);
  }
}
```

In your very case, you can also refactor your code with 2 other solutions:

- Instead of building your `layerGroup` (which is actually a [Leaflet GeoJSON Layer Group](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#geojson)) first and then add it into your `Hazards` Feature Group, make the latter a GeoJSON Layer Group from the beginning, and [`addData`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#geojson-adddata) for each of your single Features (`item`):

```js
var Hazards = L.geoJSON(null, yourOptions).addTo(map);

for (i in polygons) {
  var item = {
    "type" : "Feature",
    // etc.
  };
  // toAdd.push(item);
  Hazards.addData(item); // Directly add the GeoJSON Feature object
}
```

- Instead of building a GeoJSON Feature Object (`item`) and parse it into a Leaflet GeoJSON Layer, you can directly build a [Leaflet Polygon](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#polygon) and add it into your `Hazards` Layer/Feature Group:

```js
for (i in polygons) {
  var coords = polygons[i]["coordinates"];
  var style = getStyle(polygons[i]["category"]);
  var popup = ""; // fill it as you wish

  // Directly build a Leaflet layer instead of an intermediary GeoJSON Feature
  var itemLayer = L.polygon(coords, style).bindPopup(popup);
  itemLayer.id = polygons[i]["ID"];
  itemLayer.addTo(Hazards);
}

function getStyle(category) {
  switch (category) {
    case 'Rabid_Beavers': return {color: "#663326"};
    case 'Fire':   return {color: "#ff0000"};
    case 'Flood':   return {color: "#0000ff"};
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

As mentioned by @ghybs Leaflet.Draw doesn't support Groups or MultiPolygons. I needed the same functionality so a few years ago I created Leaflet-Geoman (previously named leaflet.pm) which supports holes, MultiPolygons, GeoJSON and LayerGroups:

[image]

https://github.com/geoman-io/leaflet-geoman

Hope it helps.

Comment: leaflet.pm is excellent. I switched to it after banging my head against the wall with Leaflet.Draw and GeoJSON FeatureCollections of MultiPolygons.

Comment: Is this package suitable for React? Because I could not find anything about it if it does.

Comment: Works just fine. No framework specific code is in the library and many companies use it with react. You have to wrap it yourself though (or there might be an existing OSS wrapper).