# Best way to convert Leaflet Geojson layers to Leaflet rectangle vector

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson, leaflet.draw

I am working on a Leaflet map application that allows users to draw shape layers and load shape layers from the backend. The users can add, edit and delete shape layers at will.

The issue arises when I want to ensure compatibility between the drawn and loaded layers. The drawn layers are created as polygon vector layers. On the other hand, the loaded layers are created as Leaflet geojson layers.

Both types of layers have very different data structure. As such, there are compatibility issues when it comes to getting data and editing the layers. For example, the Leaflet.Edit tool can easily edit the polygon vector layers, but becomes unresponsive when there are Geojson layers on the map.

In addition, the shape features can be easily retrieved in polygon vector layers, usually from the top level.

```
{  
   /** some other entries **/
   "feature":{  
      "properties":{  
         "Name":"rectangle-9d3jtxlr99",
         "Description":"",
         "Tag":"",
         "id":"rectangle-9d3jtxlr99"
      }
   }
}
```

On the other hand, getting the shape features is much messier for the geojson layers.

```
{  
   "_layers":{  
      "2998":{  
         /** other stuff **/
         "feature":{  
            "properties":{  
               "Name":"rectangle-xugcym9x4i",
               "Description":"",
               "Tag":"",
               "id":"rectangle-xugcym9x4i"
            },
            "geometry":{  
               "type":"Polygon",
               "coordinates":[  
                  /** list of coordinates **/
               ]
            },
            "type":"Feature"
         },
      }
   },
}
```

I think converting the Geojson layers to polygon vector layers will potentially solve this problem. Are there any third party Leaflet plugins that converts Geojson layers to polygon vector layers?

Comment: https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.5.0.html#layergroup-togeojson

Comment: Hi IvanSanchez, it seems like this converts vector layers to geojson, and not the other way around.

Comment: Still the same root cause as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53463078/leaflet-draw-cannot-read-property-enable-of-undefined-adding-control-to-geoj/53463994?r=SearchResults#53463994