# Leaflet Draw Will Not Delete Features that are added on page load from L.geoJSON()

Tags: leaflet, geodjango, leaflet.draw

I am loading a GeoDjango GeometryCollection from a database record and placing them on a featureGroup() using L.geoJSON(). When I try to edit or delete the individual layers, it does not work and there's no error message. However, when I use the "Clear All Layers" button, it successfully deletes all the layers. Is there somewhere I should look to figure this out?

**UPDATE**: I noticed an error message on Edit, seen below. The delete (trash icon) still does not work or provide any error message when I try to delete the items that are placed when the page is loaded.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'enable' of undefined
  at i._enableLayerEdit (leaflet.draw.js:formatted:2204)
  at i.eachLayer (leaflet.js:5)
  at i.addHooks (leaflet.draw.js:formatted:2131)
  at i.enable (leaflet.js:5)
  at i.enable (leaflet.draw.js:formatted:2115)
  at HTMLAnchorElement.s (leaflet.js:5)
```

[image]

Using Leaflet Draw 1.0.4 (Leaflet 1.6.0)

```
<script>
var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([39.828, -98.579], 4),
layer = L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}', {
  attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
  maxZoom: 18,
  id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
  tileSize: 512,
  zoomOffset: -1,
  accessToken: '<my token>'
}),
drawnItems = L.featureGroup().addTo(mymap);

L.control.layers({
  'layer': layer.addTo(mymap),
},
{
  'drawLayer': drawnItems
}).addTo(mymap);



{% if coords %}
var geos = {% autoescape off %}{{coords}}['geometries']{% endautoescape %}
$(geos).each(function() {
  L.geoJSON(this).addTo(drawnItems);
})
{% endif %}

mymap.addControl(new L.Control.Draw({
  edit: {
    featureGroup: drawnItems,
    remove: true,
  poly: {
    allowIntersection: false
  },
},
draw: {
  polyline: false,
  circle: false,
  circlemarker: false,
  polygon: {
    allowIntersection: false
  }
}
})
);
</script>
```

Comment: When you delete a feature, Please try to Zoom in or out and check if it's deleted or not, sometime layer is deleted from the map, but update is not reflected until further event.

Comment: Good idea - I checked this and even after delete they do not disappear on Zoom. I did notice an error message on the Edit though, which I will add to the question

Comment: ahh i got your problem, The draw tool delete the layers or features that are created using the draw tool, If you have loaded a geometry from database, then it cannot be edited or deleted using draw tool like that, you have to make custom code for that.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not showing a sample of GeoJSON data that reproduces the problem, it is hard to tell exactly what is the reason.

However, the error message is exactly the same as when you try editing or deleting Leaflet Layer Groups with Leaflet.draw, see [Leaflet Draw "Cannot read property 'enable' of undefined" adding control to geoJSON layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53463078/leaflet-draw-cannot-read-property-enable-of-undefined-adding-control-to-geoj/53463994?r=SearchResults#53463994)

Possible workaround: flatten your layers before adding them into the editable layer, as shown in the linked post.